# How to mimic static override?

Tags: c#, static, overriding

Every time I want to make something like a "static override" (which is not possible in C#) I find questions that say this is caused by a poor design. How would you design your code to avoid this?

Example: some game with lots of units, each has a different cost (an int or something like that), but each of the subclassses has the same cost. It would make sense here(IMHO) using an "abstract static", but that is not possible. Which is the best way to model this cases?

I usually end up creating an abstract method that returns a static variable that I have to create (and remember!) in each subclass, but then I always depend on having an instance of each class, any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use statics here at all. Simply define a base class for all concrete units, that takes the cost as initialization argument:

```
public abstract class UnitBase
{
    public int Cost { get; private set; }

    public UnitBase(int cost)
    {
        this.Cost = cost;
    }
}
```

Taking this as the base for your inheritance tree, you would then go along these lines:

```
public abstract class Unit1Base : UnitBase
{
    public Unit1() : base(<actual_cost>) { }
}

public class ConcreteUnit1 : Unit1Base {}
public class ConcreteUnit2 : Unit1Base {}
```

This way, each concrete unit will have the desired cost value...

Comment: That´s right, I think it´s possibly the way to go, but as I said to Darin Dimitrov this solution makes me depend on an instance and it makes me wonder: why do I need to have a "unitA" object, instance of class "UnitA", to know the cost of "UnitA"?

Comment: Why would you want it to be otherwise? Do you need to use the cost of Unit A somewhere without any instances of Unit A?

Comment: If you only want to know the costs, you can define them as constants in another static class. So you don't need to instantiate an instance only for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, in fact I do that (for storage purposes, mostly) but then I can´t have a polimorphic way of finding the cost, which is natural since I would be using static call, not virtual call.

Comment: @Gerard: You seem to be confused about polymorphism - object instances can be polymorphic. Types are not. Types are of the type *System.Type* (which obviously can't be cast to much else than System.Object). (Polymorphism for types themselves makes little sense: Creating an object of type *ConcreteUnit1* will always create an *ConcreteUnit1* object, never a *Unit1Base* instance - or, in other words: A type "template" for *ConcreteUnit1* will always be the type "template" for *ConcreteUnit1* and nothing else...)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully get what you mean. (Btw: The two concepts of polymorphism and static elements are technically exclusive to each other. Polymorphism requires some sort of runtime memory operations, while static entities are by definition not even located in (writeable) memory. So it's not really something that has to do with language design.)

Comment: @NWard, imagine when you have an upgrade to decrease the cost of a certain subclass, the you wouldn´t want an instance. I do this with an aditional static class that holds data, but this is not very safe since I could make a mistake, because I am not using polymorphism.

Comment: @ThomasWeller polymorphisms is not like that in all languages. But in C# it is just as you say. What I mean is that if I declare an aditional static class for storage, I can´t have a method that gets me the cost of the subclass polymorphically.

Comment: @Gerard: Answer this (based on the example given by Thomas): Assuming *Cost* is a static variable, what should `Unit1Base.Cost` return? How should such - or a similar expression - "know" whether you intend to get *ConcreteUnit1.Cost* or *ConcreteUnit2.Cost*?

Comment: @elgonzo it shouldn´t return anything because I would make it an abstract class. In fact I wouldn´t allow virtual static, but I would allow abstract static (in the dream world where I decide how C# is).

Comment: Didn't you say that the costs are all the same for all subclasses of a certain superclass? That's the point where I don't understand why you then would need polymorphism.

Comment: @Gerard: You misunderstand (not meant offensive). Objects are polymorphic, class definitions/types are not. If i say/write `Unit1Base.Cost`, now you will have to tell me whether i intended to get the costs of ConcreteUnit1 or ConcreteUnit1. Can you? No? How should the code be able to do that?

Comment: Sorry maybe it´s me who don´t understand. I want polymorphism to have a single way to create units. Imagine a barrack or something like that, it makes a UnitA, but in code it has just a Unit. Then it gets Cost of that Unit, without having to know the specific subclass.

Comment: @Gerard: If i understand you correctly, the "barrack" actually churns out object instances of UnitA, right?

Comment: @elgonzo no offense at all! I´m happy to learn. I didn´t know that, I guess that is how things are done. That means that in the end I will be forced to use the good solutions that everybody was providing, a virtual property to get me a static variable.

Comment: @Gerard: Just forget about static variables for that purpose at all. If a virtual (instance) property is suitable for you, you don't need to defer to a static variable anymore...

Comment: @elgonzo you got me hahaha in that case, instances are fine. But what if you "upgrade" the barrack so UnitA costs less? I think I would go with the aditional static class for data.

Comment: But that's perfectly possible! Just call `ConcreteUnit1.Cost` and you will always get the correct value - the one that you set when declaring (not instantiating, if that should be your concern) `Unit1Base` ...

Comment: @Gerard, i see. In the case those values should be modifiable while remaining identical for all object instances of the same type, then yes, letting your virtual property defer to a static variable makes sense :)

Comment: Would it help to handle the initial 'base class cost' as overrideable default value?

Answer (score 2):

> but each of the subclassses has the same cost.

That seems like a good candidate for a base class containing a `Cost` property that the others will inherit:

```
public virtual decimal Cost
{
    get { return 20m; }
}
```

Then if anywhere down the chain you have some other price, you could override the Cost property.

Comment: It´s a good solution, but I still would depend on an instance :(

Comment: I don't quite understand your requirement then. You said that you have some units where each subclass has a cost. So it makes perfect sense to have an instance of something to determine its cost.

Comment: It makes sense, but it also makes sense to be able to know the cost of a unit subclass, without having an instance of it.

Comment: Object instances are cheap. That's not something that you should be concerned with. This being said, static properties cannot be inherited, so you don't have much choices here. As an alternative you could write a static function which takes an enum representing the concrete unit type and which returns its Cost. This way you don't need an instance but it's a different design. From the information provided in your question it's pretty hard to tell whether this would be appropriate for your specific case.

Comment: It´s not so much about it being cheap or not, I am more worried about the purity of the design. However I can see that deep inside I am asking for someone to tell me: "yes, you can have abstract override", so this is probably the way to go.

Comment: In OOP static mmembers (fields/properties/methods) cannot be overriden. You can hide them in the derived class by declaring a static property with the same name. But that would be a horrible design IMHO.

Comment: I agree, I decided once to go with "new" but it ends always badly, eventually you forget something.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that you cannot have a `static virtual`/`override` property. This can be annoying for the case you describe, which I too have struggled with in the past.

However, you can use `static` properties... and the `new` keyword to hide the base implementation.

For example, let's define some units here:

```
public abstract class BaseUnit
{
    public static int UnitCost { get { return 10; } }
}

public class CheapUnit : BaseUnit
{
    new public static int UnitCost { get { return 5; } }
}

public class ExpensiveUnit : BaseUnit
{
    new public static int UnitCost { get { return 20; } }
}

public class MultipleUnit : BaseUnit
{
    new public static int UnitCost { get { return BaseUnit.UnitCost * 4; } }
}
```

Then a little test program to output their values:

```
    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base unit cost:\t\t{0}", BaseUnit.UnitCost);
        Console.WriteLine("Cheap unit cost:\t{0}", CheapUnit.UnitCost);
        Console.WriteLine("Expensive unit cost:\t{0}", ExpensiveUnit.UnitCost);
        Console.WriteLine("Multiple unit cost:\t{0}", MultipleUnit.UnitCost);
    }
```

And we get...

```
Base unit cost:         10
Cheap unit cost:        5
Expensive unit cost:    20
Multiple unit cost:     40
```

Ah ha! Exactly what we want. I'm not 100% happy with this solution but I don't know a better way without having to create an instance which I think it silly to access a polymorphic class constant. So I just do it this way.

**EDIT:** In cases where I found myself doing this, I often opted to move this kind of 'lookup' logic into a manager (singleton) class. For example, `UnitManager` or similar, where I could pass in a type name (`"CheapUnit"`) and it would look up the cost in a `Dictionary`.

Just a quick mockup idea:

```
sealed class UnitManager
{
    static readonly UnitManager instance = new UnitManager();

    public static UnitManager Instance { get { return instance; } }

    Dictionary<string, int> unitCostDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // Ignore Case of Keys

    public int LookupUnitCost(string unitType)
    {
        int unitCost = 0;
        unitCostDictionary.TryGetValue(unitType, out unitCost);

        return unitCost;
    }
}
```

This also allows dynamic unit cost and centralized notifications when a unit cost may change.

Comment: You know what I mean... woudln´t it be nice?? I don´t like this solutions "so much", but it is indeed the most similar to a static override.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Factory class (static) that returns the instance you want but have the declaration of the factory method return the abstract type?

Comment: Right, but a I don´t think a singleton is the solution for a class that I will need to instantiate, eventually.

Comment: why not create a factory that returns the instance you want but have the declaration of the factory method return the abstract class?

Answer (score 0):

While I sometimes miss the ability to override a static method in .net, it wouldn't be for this scenario. 
Aside from simply using inheritance which you seem to be dead against for some reason I can't fathom, another way to do it might be, to delegate cost to one static class which took unit type as an argument.
Another would be to make cost an attribute of the class and look it up via reflection.

Comment: I´m not so much against it, I just miss the chance to get any variable that belongs to the whole class (that is, a static variable) without having to create a non-static virtual method to achieve polymorphism.